# How many inodes does a file, a folder take?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

After checking a lot of information on the Internet, it is still not quite clear for me how many inodes a file and a folder takes.

Also, I noticed that inodes are shown in kilobytes and not as cardinal numbers.

So how to count the number of inodes required for a file or a folder?

P.S. My bad, it seems that `K` and `M` in the output of `$ sudo df -ih/` mean thousands and millions and not kilobytes and megabytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file has one single [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) since it is the inode that uniquely identifies the file. You can have several names/paths pointing to the same inode, this is called ["hard links"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link).

When you list a file with `ls -l`, a column is the number of references to the inode (i.e. the number of paths that lead to it). For files it is usually `1`, unless hard links have been explicitly created:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 20 12:11 ./
drwxrwxrwt 29 root root 86016 Aug 20 12:11 ../
-rw-r--r--  3 root root     0 Aug 20 12:10 linked1
-rw-r--r--  3 root root     0 Aug 20 12:10 linked2
-rw-r--r--  3 root root     0 Aug 20 12:10 linked3
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     0 Aug 20 12:10 single
```

Above, `single` is the name of a file with a single path to it, while `linked*` are three names for the same inode. If you do `ls -il` to show the inodes:

```
>>>ls -il *
24641901 -rw-r--r-- 3 root root 0 Aug 20 12:10 linked1
24641901 -rw-r--r-- 3 root root 0 Aug 20 12:10 linked2
24641901 -rw-r--r-- 3 root root 0 Aug 20 12:10 linked3
24641866 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 20 12:10 single
```

This confirms that the three `linked*` files are actually the same inode. If we `rm linked2`, the reference count in the remaining names is decreased:

```
>>>ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 20 12:15 ./
drwxrwxrwt 29 root root 86016 Aug 20 12:15 ../
-rw-r--r--  2 root root     0 Aug 20 12:10 linked1
-rw-r--r--  2 root root     0 Aug 20 12:10 linked3
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     0 Aug 20 12:10 single
```

For directories the references count is normally 2 plus the number of subdirectories (AFAIK, the "normal" reference (from the parent), the `.` in the directory itself, and the `..` in each subdirectory).

Otherwise, a file (or directory) can use several allocation blocks, depending on contents and this can change during the lifetime of the file.

Comment: Why are inodes shown in kilobytes and megabytes then `$ sudo df -ih/
`? By the way, I also saw the information that a file can take a different amount of inodes depending on the file system
https://opensource.com/article/18/4/ext4-filesystem

Comment: The "Inodes" count in `df -i` is the number of inodes in the file system (the number of files it can hold). It is a count, not a size in KB/MB. Did you check the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)?

Comment: About: http://opensource.com/article/18/4/ext4-filesystem this severely contradicts Wikipedia, so unless you find other references mentioning this, I'll ascribe this to a brain lapse by the author.

Comment: Yes, I checked Wiki - it did not answer my question. So `K` and `M` there just means thousands and millions? I thought they were kilobytes and megabytes.

Comment: Yes. Just counts, not sizes.

Comment: "For directories the references count is normally 2 plus the number of subdirectories" -- in ext. Other filesystems may vary.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks. I will edit my question then.